# TFS Rest API Queries

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-sdk

We are using TFS 2015 and will be moving to TFS 2017 version.

As we have a lot of Collections (approx. 17), there are times we have to manually check across all collections for values. To mitigate this I am planning to query TFS Rest APIs, in order to fetch values.

I have certain queries regarding how to go about with Rest API, as we can use the following approaches:

1.) Use Nuget packages like:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient
```

This requires the following code:

```
//Prompt user for credential
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(vstsCollectionUrl), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, pat));

//create a wiql object and build our query
Wiql wiql = new Wiql()
{
    Query = "Select [State], [Title] " +
            "From WorkItems " +
            "Where [Work Item Type] = 'Bug' " +
            "And [System.TeamProject] = '" + project + "' " +
            "And [System.State] <> 'Closed' " +
            "Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc"
};

//create http client and query for resutls
WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
Wiql query = new Wiql() { Query = "SELECT [Id], [Title], [State] FROM workitems WHERE [Work Item Type] = 'Bug' AND [Assigned To] = @Me" };
WorkItemQueryResult queryResults = witClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(query).Result;

//Display reults in console
if (queryResults == null || queryResults.WorkItems.Count() == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Query did not find any results");
}
```

2.) Another approach is hitting Rest APIs using HttpClient with PAT or Alternate Credentials, like the following:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(
        "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
            $"{username}:{password}")));

    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(
        $"https://dev.azure.com/{account}/_apis/projects").Result)
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        repsonseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

What is the difference between the 2 approaches and which is the recommended approach and would work with the TFS 2017 version?

Any help or suggestions or links would be great.

**Also does OAuth Authentication work with TFS, as it does with Azure Devops?**

Answer (score 2):

The `*HttpClient` classes from the nuget packages are a wrapper for the REST API. So they are more high level and should be easier to use. Also they define classes for all the result and parameter objects. As they target the same API they are equivalently supported.

---

> Also does OAuth Authentication work with TFS, as it does with Azure Devops ?

No it doesn't as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops

> The following guidance is intended for Azure DevOps Services users, since OAuth 2.0 is not supported on Team Foundation Server or Azure DevOps Server.

Answer (score 1):

I use the first option on my projects. In supported by MS and you can prompts creds from users or use PAT. Additionally you use clear methods with known results without defining your own classes.